# How to delete all the lines after the last occurence of pattern?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i want to delete all the lines after the last occurence of pattern except the pattern itself

file.txt

```
honor
apple
redmi
nokia
apple
samsung
lg
htc
```

file.txt what i want

```
honor
apple
redmi
nokia
apple
```

what i have tried

```
sed -i '/apple/q' file.txt
```

this deletes all the line after the first occurence of pattern -

```
honor
```

Comment: Reverse the file, delete everything before the pattern, then reverse the result.

Comment: file is actually very big .will it have any issue ? isthere any other efficient way ?

Comment: What should it do if the string isn't found -- print everything or nothing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, robust 2-pass approach using almost no memory:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/apple/) hit=NR; next} {print} FNR==hit{exit}' file file
honor
apple
redmi
nokia
apple
```

If that doesn't execute fast enough **THEN** it's time to try some alternatives to see if any produce a performance improvement.

Comment: Why does the filename argument need to be passed in twice?  Can you explain the mechanics of what awk is doing under the covers in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Reverse the file, print everything starting from the first occurrence of the pattern, then reverse the result:

```
tac file.txt | sed -n '/apple/,$p' | tac > newfile.txt
```

You can find the line number of the last match, then use that to print the first N lines of the file:

```
line=$(awk '/apple/ { line=NR } END {print line}')
head -n $line file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: If `apple` didn't exist in the file then those scripts would produce no output but I'd think the expected behavior would be to print the whole file. You need to add `file.txt` at the end of the awk script btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reverse the file as Barmar suggests, you will either have to read the file in reverse using lower level tools (eg, fseek) or read it twice:

```
sed $(awk '/apple/{a=NR}END{print a+1}' input),\$d input
```

(Note that if the pattern does not appear in the file, this will output nothing.  That's an edge case you should worry about.)

Comment: Well spotted on the edge case! You could fix that with `print (a?a:NR)+1` of course though I personally prefer to identify the lines to print rather than the lines to delete (feels like more "positive" logic to me) e.g.: `sed -n $(awk '/apple/{a=NR}END{print (a?a:NR)}' input),\$p input` and of course some enclosing quotes would be nice and you could use `head` instead of `sed`...

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/apple/,$!b;//!H;//{x;//p;x;h};${x;P};d' file
```

Print as usual any lines that are not from the first appearance of `apple` to the end of the file. For lines within the above range, append lines that do not contain the word `apple` to the hold space (HS). Lines that do contain the word `apple`, first swap to the HS and print any line there if the word `apple` is there, then replace the HS with the line containing `apple`. Delete all lines other than the last line. At the endof file print the first line of the HS and delete the remaining lines.

If slurping a large file is not a problem use:

```
sed -rz 's/(.*apple[^\n]*).*/\1\n/' file
```

This uses greed to capture all lines before and including the word `apple`.

Answer (score 0):

here is another `awk` without scanning the file twice

```
$ awk 'f       {buf=buf ORS $0} 
       /apple/ {f=1; if(buf)print buf; buf=$0} 
       !f' file

honor
apple
redmi
nokia
apple
```

Comment: That would produce unexpected output if `apple` appeared on the line immediately before the last `apple` line in the input (it would be printed twice). The OP also mentioned in a comment that he's concerned about his file being big so YMMV with storing blocks of it in memory as it might work today and then fail later for some other distribution of "apple"s.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having everything in memory, you can do:

```
$ awk '/^apple$/{last=NR} 
              {lines[NR]=$0}
     END{for(li=1;li<=last;li++) print lines[li]}' file
honor
apple
redmi
nokia
apple
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are dealing with large input I would go with a two-pass `coreutils` solution, e.g.:

```
n=$(grep -Fn apple infile | tail -n1 | cut -d: -f1)
[ -n "$n" ] && head -n$n infile > outfile
```

This uses *grep's* fixed string matching (`-F`) to find every line containing apples. Then *head* is used to extract the relevant lines.

You did not specify what happens when no apples are found, so this solution does nothing when that occurs.

Comment: You missed a closing ')'  (I can't edit your answer by myself)